# Send and Decode Object Array via JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, object

I have an array of `People` objects. I'm sending them to PHP but the way to get my objects back in PHP so I can manipulate them seems convoluted. Here's what I have, but it doesn't seem to return anything back to my AJAX Call. Right now I just have 1 `Person` Object in my array but I want to make sure everything is fine before I advance. In short, when I decode my JSON shouldn't it convert it to an Object in PHP? In the end I want an array of PHP objects that are `People`

Jquery

```
var people = new Array();
var person = new Person("Michael", "Jackson", 50);
localStorage.setItem(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName, JSON.stringify(person));

function Person(firstName, lastName, age)
{
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    this.age=age;
}

function getStorage(){
    var tempPerson;
    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
    {
        tempPerson = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        people.push(tempPerson);
    }
}

function getPeople(){
    $.post(
        "people.php",
        {people : people},
        function(data) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
}

getStorage();
getPeople();
```

PHP

```
<?php
$personObj = Array();
$people = $_POST['people'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($people); $i++)
{
    foreach($people[$i] as $person)
    {
        $streamObj = json_decode($person);
    }
}

echo $personObj->$firstName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to making the change suggested by @Even Hahn, you need to change the data you are posting as follows:

```
$.post(
    "people.php",
    {people : JSON.stringify(people)},
    function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

This way a single name/value pair is posted. The name is "people" and the value is a JSON encoded string of the array of `Person` objects.

Then when you call the following in the PHP code, you are decoding that JSON encoded string into an array on the PHP side.

```
$people = json_decode($_POST['people']);
```

I also see where you assign `$personObj` to an array, but I don't see where you put anything in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your JSON decoding in your PHP:

```
$personObj = Array();
$people = json_decode($_POST['people']);

for($i = 0; $i < count($people); $i++)
{
    foreach($people[$i] as $person)
    {
        $streamObj = $person;
    }
}

echo $personObj->$firstName;
```

This is because `$_POST['people']` is a JSON string which needs to be decoded.

Comment: I tried that and it said it needed a string. People is an array. I'm pushing it into the array at getStorage();

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the PHP codes should be look like this:

```
<?php
$personObj = Array();
$people = $_POST["people"];

foreach($people as $p)
{
    $val = str_replace("\\","",$p);
    $personObj = json_decode($val);
}

echo $personObj->firstName;
?>
```